# Error thrown when writing subprocess pid to a log file

Tags: python-2.7, debian, subprocess

I have a python script that runs a couple of subprocesses.

What I am trying to achieve is that i'd like to write the subprocess process IDs to a separate log file. The subprocess can run for even few hours, so I'd like to keep track of them with the PIDs.

Somehow I am unable to write the PIDs to a log file, as I bump into exceptions.

```
tmprocess = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', logstashbin, '-f', tmconf], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
tmprocess.wait()
segmentprocess = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', logstashbin, '-f', segmentconf], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).pid
print segmentprocess

try:
    pidfile = open("pid.log", "a+")
    try:
        pidfile.write(segmentprocess)
    finally:
        pidfile.close()
except:
    raise IOError("Error")
```

This is the output I get,

```
1237
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./init.py", line 285, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./init.py", line 282, in main
    init(arg)
  File "./init.py", line 264, in init
    run_logstash(langPath)
  File "./init.py", line 228, in run_logstash
    raise IOError("Error")
IOError: Error
```

Although the PID is being printed, it is not getting written to the file.
Note: If I just write some random string to the log file by replacing "segmentprocess", then it does work. So there is nothing wrong with file open.

Comment: Your indentation looks incorrect. Can you check it? Also, the stack trace you provided appears to throw a different exception than is in your code. Is there something we're not seeing? Can you include the line number range that you have provided? Also, if you're trying to debug the exception, why re-raise a different exception? Just let the real exception bubble up and post it here. Do not catch it, and if you do, make sure you just `raise` again. instead of `raise IOError("Error")`.

Comment: @JamieCounsell, thanks a lot for the heads up. I fixed the bad indentation above in my post (my original code doesn't have bad indentation problem). I actually fixed the error, it was not smart of me to catch the error. When I removed the try, except block, I did see the actual error "TypeError: expected a character buffer object". I just had to do typecasting and the error disappeared. Such a noob mistake. I guess I'm better of deleting this post? thanks again for your help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I posted my comment as an answer. Either delete the post or mark as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace you provided appears to throw a different exception than is in your code. Is there something we're not seeing? Can you include the line number range that you have provided? Also, if you're trying to debug the exception, why re-raise a different exception? Just let the real exception bubble up and post it here. Do not catch it, and if you do, make sure you just `raise` again. Instead of

```
raise IOError("Error")
```

You should just

```
raise
```

Or not try/except at all:

```
pidfile = open("pid.log", "a+")
try:
    pidfile.write(segmentprocess)
finally:
    pidfile.close()
```